# How to skip space

Tags: groovy

So I have a text file that contains this-

```
version.build: 900
version.maintenance: 0
version.major: 1
version.minor: 37
```

And I want to print this- **ccsmp_v_1.37.0.900** To do this I am doing this below-

```
      def baseList = readFile('text1.txt').split('\n') as List
      def map = [:]
      for (el in baseList) {
          if (el.contains(':')) {
              def parts = el.split(':')
              map[parts[0]] = parts[1]
          }
      }
      def SVN_TAG="ccsmp_v_${map['version.major']}.${map['version.minor']}.${map['version.maintenance']}.${map['version.build']}"

println "SVN_TAG: $SVN_TAG"
```

But when I run this I get spaces between each letters-

**ccsmp_v_ 1. 37. 0. 900**

Is there any way to remove these spaces from my output.  Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def parts = el.split(':')` splits the `version.build: 900` string into two parts, `version.build` and  `900` (notice the leading space)

Change `map[parts[0]] = parts[1]` to `map[parts[0]] = parts[1].trim()` to remove the leading space

Comment: You should mark it as an an answer and upvote it.